# Parallel Access with ORACLE_DATAPUMP to unload data

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration, datapump

I just have been introduced to the concept of parallel access with ORACLE_DATAPUMP to unload data. But couldn't understand it properly - regarding the parallelism. So with a tiny amount of code can anyone help me to understand how a parallel process starts and loads the data to its respective files.

***Code:***

```
CREATE TABLE all_objects_xt
  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (
     TYPE ORACLE_DATAPUMP
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY xt_dir
       LOCATION ( 'allobj1.dmp', 'allobj2.dmp' )
  )
  PARALLEL
  AS
     SELECT *
     FROM   all_objects;
```

*For parallel unloads, file offsets are distributed among parallel processes for multiple concurrent processing on a file or within a set of files. - anyway can it be explained to visualize how it(offset concept) happened in real time programming.?*

Comment: This post goes beyond all the away others.. :( so anyone could help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

First thing for Parallel clause of Oracle: It depends on numbers of CPU. Generally it takes effect of number of cpu x 2 = parallel degree of execution. Second thing, parallel operation depends on PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS parameter too because this is maximum boundary limitation.

You are creating an external table with option of ORACLE_DATAPUMP driver from 2 different dump files. Data will be populated whenever this external object is referencing. You can put Parallel 4 or Parallel 6 clause too during creation of this external table. It means either 4 parallel threads will be performing task or 6 will be performing task.

If you want to check parallel processing of your above object then do following test.

Open 1 session as owner or privilege user of your external table and execute select query. Immediately open another session as SYSDBA or DBA and execute queries from following data dictionary views.

select * from V$PQ_SESSTAT;
select * from V$PQ_SYSSTAT;

V$PQ_SESSTAT will give you accurate result of existing parallel operation. Means how many query executed and how many parallel server are being used by query. I hope you are clear now.